# Is there a Stack Exchange site for clothing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering if there is a Stack Exchange site for discussing clothing questions; for example, how to dress in the workplace, in casual situations and for certain events.

If not, could you kindly point out some websites on this topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [clothing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19254/clothing-and-accessories) on Area 51 that hasn't gotten too far. Currently, there's a more established community on [WikiAnswers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/FAQMAP/2220).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the clothing proposal has a long way to go.

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer (March 2016).

---

There's a new Area 51 proposal for [Clothes and Fashion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93374/clothes-fashion) (the old one that Ryan Berger mentioned failed), whose description reads:

> For creators of clothes, fashion experts, costume enthusiasts and everybody to whom clothes are more than just something to cover one’s skin.

It only has 13 followers, though, and doesn't seem likely to succeed.

---

As far as already-existing sites go, there are a couple where you might be able to ask *some* questions about clothing, but there must be many questions that wouldn't be on-topic on any current SE site.

You mention "how to dress in the workplace"; this could be on-topic on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Certain questions about clothing would also be on-topic on [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange, where they have a [clothing tag](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) with 114 questions.

<sub>Naturally, the standard disclaimers apply: if you're not familiar with the site, read their tour and guide to on-topicness before posting any questions there.</sub>

Comment: The Clothes and Fashion proposal has also been deleted (as of Feb 2018)